# Upgrading Ubuntu to version 18.10 on the i386 architecture

Tags: upgrade

Upgrading from 18.04 to 18.10 on the i386 architecture are not supported at this time.
How soon will it be supported on the i386 architecture?

Answer (score 2):

Xubuntu and Lubuntu still support 32 bits for the 18.10 release, but not the Ubuntu 18.10 release.  Check your machine specs, it may actually be 64 bit, and you are just running a 32 bit release.  In that case, you cannot upgrade, but will need to backup your files, install the 64 bit version, then restore your files.

Even Xubuntu will be dropping 32 bit support for 19.04 (https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Xubuntu-No-More-32-bit) leaving Lubuntu as your only 32 bit option for after April 2019.

Comment: This only applies to the *installer ISOs* - the 32bit upgrade process from the discussion I've read on the email threads that I'm on will still be open from 18.04/18.10 -> 19.04 - but eventually I believe all 32bit support will be gone - no idea when that'll be though.